# sending mouse clicks from Flash to JS

Tags: javascript, flash

Is it possible to send mouse events from flash to JS? I have flash images for good UI, but underneath it is all JS. I want the flash mouse click event to be sent to JS, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send almost any kind of data from Flash to JavaScript (and viceversa) using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), which allows you to invoke JavaScript functions passing parameters from your Flash AS3 code.

Answer (score 1):

You can send any data in both directions between flash and js. Its known as External Interface.

Here are the official docs.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

**EDIT:**

There are lots of tutorials on the net, the process has not changed in years, have a look at this [tutorial](http://lightness.co.uk/external-interface-examples/).

Comment: @user1711343 Ive added a link, but seriously you can find many tutorials just searching on google.